# wire shark log file conversion to text file through cli (in windows7)

Tags: wireshark, pcap, file-conversion, wireshark-dissector

For some automation purpose I have below requirements for the Wireshark log file(.pcap).
1-Conversion of Wireshark logs(.pcap file ) to text file with detail of packets.
2-Conversion of Wireshark logs (.pcap file) to text file with some filter (eg: bssgp.pdu_type == 0x00) with detail of packets.

I know how to convert the wireshark files to text file through GUI,
But I need the cli commands for the same to automate the procedure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `.pcap` file to text output, you can run:

```
tshark -V -r file.pcap > file.txt
```

If you only want to convert certain packets that match a Wireshark display filter, then using your filter, you can run:

```
tshark -Y "bssgp.pdu_type == 0x00" -V -r file.pcap > file.txt
```

If the `-V` option provides too much detail, you can limit the detail to specific protocol(s) by using the `-O` option instead.  For example, to provide details for bssgp only and a summary for all other protocols, try:

```
tshark -Y "bssgp.pdu_type == 0x00" -O bssgp -r file.pcap > file.txt
```

Refer to the [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man page for more details about these options.

Comment: Thanks Chirstophe!! ?It helpled .